# How to get childAutoID in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my database is setup

```
  "Meters" : {
    "00090850378" : {
      "-MD6DxNdQVL-nJw_w-K_" : {
        "Date" : "25-07-2020",
        "Meter Reading" : "298",
        "Time" : "20:28"
      },
      "-MD6Ll4LrKgY6h8BEMNf" : {
        "Date" : "25-07-2020",
        "Meter Reading" : "84126",
        "Time" : "21:02"
      },
      "-MD6NwofplQej4s13faW" : {
        "Date" : "25-07-2020",
        "Meter Reading" : "6524",
        "Time" : "21:12"
      }
    },
    "878251458532" : {
      "-MD6O5sTQdoPz3clrrpL" : {
        "Date" : "25-07-2020",
        "Meter Reading" : "848555",
        "Time" : "21:12"
      },
      "-MD6OCq7QZm1Hn7AOvlv" : {
        "Date" : "25-07-2020",
        "Meter Reading" : "848555",
        "Time" : "21:13"
      }
    }
  }
```

"Meters" contains a list of meter numbers in which each reading is named by an AutoID and the children are the reading, time and date. What I am trying to do is get make an array of meter readings per meter. The problem I'm having is how do I get a list of the AutoIDs to access each child?

Comment: Are you using Firestore or the realtime db?

Comment: I’m using real-time dB @sands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the name of the child nodes of a snapshot, you can loop over its `children` property.

If you **do** know the name of the child property, you can access it with `childSnapshot(forPath:)` and its value with `.value`.

Combining those two pieces of knowledge leads to this code to read, traverse and print your data structure:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  for meterSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
    print(meterSnapshot.key) // prints "00090850378", "878251458532"
    for readingSnapshot in meterSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
      print(readingSnapshot.key) // prints "-MD6DxNdQVL-nJw_w-K_", "-MD6Ll4LrKgY6h8BEMNf", etc
      print(readingSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath:"Meter Reading").value) // "298", "84126", etc
    }
  }
})
```